# Archiva search doesn't show anything

Tags: maven-3, archiva

I just wanted to give Archiva a try, but stumpled over some behaviour very quickly.

So, I downloaded the current release (1.3.6) on my Kubuntu machine, extracted it, started it via `./archiva console`, put the archiva repository into the `mirrors` section in mavens `settings.xml` and made a maven build.

Everything seemed fine so far, I was able to browse the Archiva repository and saw all the artifacts of my build.

But when I type anything in the search box, I don't get results. For example I see the artifact with the id `junit`, but when I type `junit` in the search, it tells me that no results were found.

The documentation states that files are indexed after download, so what else may I have done wrong?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you solve it anyhow?

Comment: @Kungi: No, I switched to Nexus.

Comment: I solved the problem by restarting Archiva after "some time" and everything was there.

Answer (score 0):

Does junit is an artifact of your build ?
It was probably already locally in your repository so no need to download tru Archiva that's why it's not here.
Note last version 1.4* download index from central repository and display result for search.
The 1.4-M4 (not yet released but I hope soon) will download the artifact too to show more details.

Comment: I may have it in my local repository, but as I said, when I go to the archiva web frontend and browse the internal repository, I'll find the artifact junit there. But if I type it under search, I do not.

Comment: you must probably do a scanning to index those files.

Comment: I did "scan repository now", but it doesn't help. The point is, the search does not find anything, despite the fact that the Archiva GUI let me browse through the internal repository and shows me tons of stuff, how can that be? I fear that I miss something very basic - what I did was unpacking the latest stable release 1.3.6 onto my Linux machine, started `./archiva console`, let some build run which fetches a lot of stuff from the Maven Central Repository through Archiva (due to mirror configuration in Maven) and nothing of that can be searched.

Comment: It didn't help either, strange... I tried nexus and artifactory instead and it worked there, so i will choose one of them